# (0,0) coordinates of a view that is placed in the middle of the screen

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I have an ImageView placed in the center of the screen (For that I used `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`). But when I call the methods `getX()` and `getY()` I receive 0 (zero) for both of them.

I think the problem is the xml attribute `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`. Ie it doesn't actually change the place of the view on the screen.

Here the xml file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fundal">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/playbtn"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here's where I call the methods:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drag);

    ImageView img =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    Log.d("DEBUG_TAG", "Coordinates: "+img.getX()+" "+img.getY());
}
```

Comment: please post the code of the xml layout and the code of where you're calling getX()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem might be caused because ViewGroups don't layout their children immediately.

You can use a globalLayoutListener in order to see when your view is completely initialised and has the coordinates set.

```
// view will be the parent view containing your ImageView.
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
    new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // Here you can call the getX() and getY()...

            // Don't forget to remove your listener when you are done with it.
            view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok the problem is that you're asking for the position of the view but the view has not been laied out yet, you can use an `OnGlobalLayoutListener` like this

```
final View rootView = findViewById(R.id.root_view);
final ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = rootView.getViewTreeObserver();
ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener onGlobalLayoutListener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {

        Log.d("DEBUG_TAG", "Coordinates: "+img.getX()+" "+img.getY());

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
            rootView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        } else {
            rootView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    }
};
```